# Optimal way to link User to custom Object

Tags: lookup, architecture, data-model

We have Department as a custom object and want to store Department for our Users. I have come up against a brick's wall since Salesforce doesn't allow to store lookup on User object.

Please upvote the idea  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007WKpAAM

My question is - What will be the best way to link Users with Department? We need to have a separate Department object as we want to store additional information here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were tasked with connecting Departments with Users, I would actually make a new custom object called something like Department Members.  I would then use this as a junction object between Users and Departments.  You are going to like this a lot more, because on the junction object you are going to be able to add a bunch of custom logic and fields and not have to deal with the User object (trust me it's a pain.)

For instance if you needed to know that a Department Member was "Authorized" or not for a specific department, then only having that relationship with the User wouldn't make sense.  It would cause problems because only having one "Authorized" field on the User object, wouldn't allow a user to have multiple Authorization statuses for different departments.

If Junction Objects are new to you, please see this Salesforce KB article about Many-to-Many relationships https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&type=0

Answer (score 2):

Having a specific `Department Members` objet like @patrick mentioned is a good option, especially if you want to store other attributes specifically to do with how the User is related to that department (just like a proper junction object).

If you want a sort of *"here is my object for all custom stuff related to a user"*, you could potentially create a `User Extension` object, which we have done on some projects.

You can then put in all the extended user attributes you want to, whether they are lookups, text, date etc. That way all your user attributes are in a single place.

There are pros and cons to both options, especially if you are trying to keep your data as normalised as you can, but sometimes the `User Extension` object just makes more practical sense.